# What does "sign on" here mean?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

What does "sign on" here mean?

> Americans were quick to **sign on**, registering more than seven million phone numbers on the first day.

Answer (score 1):

The context seems to suggest:

[join](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/join) or [subscribe](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/subscribe)

Answer (score -1):

[sign on](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sign%20on)

> to engage oneself by or as if by a signature

Comment: does sign on here means something like reserve?